# Agregar imagen de fondo a un JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

Tengo un error al agregar una imagen de fondo a un `JFrame`. ¿Cuál es el problema?

**Código completo de mi JFrame:**

```
package interfaz;

import static com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class InicioSesion extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static BufferedImage imageBackground = null;
    public InicioSesion() {
        initComponents();

        //Situamos el JDialog en el centro de la pantalla.
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //No redimensionable.
        setResizable(false);

        try{
            BufferedImage imageBackground = ImageIO.read(getResourceAsStream("iniciosesion.png"));
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
            Graphics2D g2 = ((Graphics2D) g);
            g2.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at interfaz.InicioSesion.<init>(InicioSesion.java:26)
    at interfaz.InicioSesion$1.run(InicioSesion.java:143)
```

La imagen está en el mismo directorio que el archivo .java, para que no sea problema de ruta.

Comment: Por favor agrega si al final de tu método `initComponents()` tienes alguna llamada como `pack()` o `setVisible()` por favor, estoy un 99% seguro que allí está le problema. Adicionalmente trata siempre de poner un [mcve]

Comment: No tengo ninguna de esas dos funciones.

Comment: Para mí es claro por qué te sale en null, pero quiero ver tu código de initComponents para explicártelo mejor.

Comment: Edito la pregunta y tienes TODO mi código.

Answer (score 1):

El camino es básicamente cargarla como un BufferedImage y luego pintarla haciendo un override del método de `JComponent` dentro de la clase del panel

```
BufferedImage imageBackground = ImageIO.read(getResourceAsStream("ruta/a/tu/imagen.png"));

...
// el override de este método pinta la imagen y queda detrás de todos los componentes del panel.
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        Graphics2D g2 = ((Graphics2D) g);
        g2.drawImage(imageBackground, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Me sale este error. Edito la pregunta. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!

Comment: Es porque la ruta a tu recurso no es correcta y carga un recurso nulo. Por eso el ejemplo indica que debes especificar la ruta a tu imagen. Desde el directorio src/main, debe haber un resources. Si tiene subdirectorios y allí está tu imagen, debes indicar la ruta. :)

Comment: El archivo iniciosesion.png pertenece al mismo directorio que el archivo .java, por eso no puse la ruta completa. Pero aunque agregue la imagen a un directorio "src/imagenes/" no me la recoge. BufferedImage imageBackground = ImageIO.read(getResourceAsStream("src//imagenes//iniciosesion.png"));

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar @Alfabravo

Comment: @omaza1990 lo lamento, no he podido sentarme a mirar esto. Más tarde espero poder dedicarle otro rato para ver qué falta.

Comment: No te preocupes y gracias @Alfabravo Tengo unos caos de ideas que no consigo solucionar. Sorry.

Comment: Creo que mi problema viene a raiz de hacer mal el componente CardLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error se puede deber a dos posibles detalles:

> import static com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream;

Ese import es de sun y no debería de usarse por razones de portabilidad y se trata del **Byte Code Engineering Library** o BCEL por sus siglas, la forma normal de crear un stream para importar una imágen es:

```
Image imageBackground = ImageIO.read(NombreDeTuClase.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ruta/a/tu/imagen.png"));
```

Mi segunda teoría es que en tu método initComponents tienes una llamada

```
setVisible(true);
```

Esto forzaría el renderizado y como en ese momento lo definiste como null a tu imágen te daría le error:

```
static BufferedImage imageBackground = null;
```

Dependiendo de los componentes que tengas y como hayas configurado tu JFrame en initComponents puede ser un componente ligero (lightweight) o un componente pesado y mandar llamadas a las rutinas de pintado tanto automáticamente como de manera explícita como te lo explica [esta documentación](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html).

Ahora si no fuera el caso y por alguna improbable razón llegara hasta la parte en que tienes:

```
    try{
        BufferedImage imageBackground = ImageIO.read(getResourceAsStream("iniciosesion.png"));
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

El valor de tu variable de clase `imageBackground` (Que por su  nombre totalmente calificado sería `interfaz.InicioSesion.imageBackground`) tampoco se cambiaría, esto debido a que estás guardando todo en una variable que se llama `imageBackground` que solo vivie en tu constructor, pero nunca le asocias su valor a la instancia que creas; , y si las comparas usando los nombres totalmente cualificador notarás fácilmente que no son lo mismo (`imageBackground` e `interfaz.InicioSesion.imageBackground`)

Comment: La explicación está muy bien y es profesional pero no me solucionaste en el problema del código. Me sigue apareciendo el error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! aun tras haber realizado tus "cambios".

Comment: Como te dije es imposible resolver tu problema en particular sin por lo menos el código completo y la estructura de carpetas. Así que por la falta de información pretendo resolver tu problema, sino ayudar a alguien que tenga un problema similar, ya que es la primera vez que veo que se registra este tipo de problema en el sitio.

Comment: Ese es mi código completo del JFrame. Así que poco más puedo añadir... me sale ese error.