# el archivo Jar no se ejecuta (NetBeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

He desarrollado una aplicacion java con netbeans en windows 10 de 64 bits y decidi crear el ejecutable para distribuirlo el ejecutable se creo correctamente en la carpeta dist como sucede en netbeans el problema es que el archivo jar no se ejecuta cuando se le da doble click tratándolo de iniciar por CMD me sale el siguiente error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at rompecabezas.Board.<init>(Board.java:28)                                                                          
at rompecabezas.Rompecabezas.<init>(Rompecabezas.java:48)                                                               
at rompecabezas.Rompecabezas.main(Rompecabezas.java:55)
```

aqui esta el archivo Rompecabezas.java

```
   package rompecabezas;


   import java.awt.Container;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;

   public class Rompecabezas extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

   private JButton Siguiente;
   private int Contador;
   public static Board board;
   public static Container Contenedor;
   private BufferedImage Imagen;
   
   
   public Rompecabezas() {
       Contador = Figuras.getCompletado();

       Siguiente = new JButton("Revolver");

       Siguiente.setBounds(0, 650, 500, 30);
       Siguiente.addActionListener(this);
           
       add(Siguiente);

       this.setTitle("Rompecabezas");
       this.setSize(700, 730);
       this.setResizable(true);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       this.setResizable(false);
       Contenedor = this.getContentPane();
       
           try {
               Imagen = ImageIO.read(new File("src/Imagenes/(1).png"));
           } catch (IOException ex) {
              
           }
       
       board = new Board(3, Imagen);
       Contenedor.add(board);
       this.setVisible(true);

   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Rompecabezas rompecabezas = new Rompecabezas();
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (e.getSource() == Siguiente) {
             Rompecabezas rompecabezas = new Rompecabezas();
           }
   }
   
}
```

aqui esta el archivo Board.java

```
     package rompecabezas;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    public static Cell[][] board;
    public ArrayList<Cell> completeBoard = new ArrayList<>();
    private int Dimension;
    private int x, y;
    private int Fancho, Falto;
    private JLabel vacio;

    public Board(int Dimension, BufferedImage rompecabezas) {
        this.Dimension = Dimension;
        board = new Cell[Dimension][Dimension];
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        Fancho = rompecabezas.getWidth() / Dimension;
        Falto = rompecabezas.getHeight() / Dimension;

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Dimension; j++) {
                if (i == Dimension - 1 && j == Dimension - 1) {
                    continue;
                }

                completeBoard.add(new Cell(i, j, new Figuras(i, j, new ImageIcon(rompecabezas.getSubimage(x, y, Fancho, Falto)), Dimension)));
                x += Fancho;
            }
            x = 0;
            y += Falto;
        }
        Desordenar();

        Remover();

    }

    public void Desordenar() {

        Random Generador = new Random();
        ArrayList<Cell> copia = new ArrayList<Cell>(completeBoard);
        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Dimension; j++) {
                if (i == Dimension - 1 && j == Dimension - 1) {
                    board[i][j] = new Cell(i, j);
                    continue;
                }
                int Aleatorio = Generador.nextInt(completeBoard.size());
                completeBoard.get(Aleatorio).getFiguras().setxPos(i);
                completeBoard.get(Aleatorio).getFiguras().setyPos(j);
                board[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, completeBoard.get(Aleatorio).getFiguras());
                completeBoard.remove(Aleatorio);
            }
        }
        completeBoard = copia;
        Remover();

    }

    private void Actualizar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Dimension; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Dimension; j++) {

                if (board[i][j].getFiguras() == null) {
                    vacio = new JLabel();
                    vacio.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Fancho, Falto));
                    this.add(vacio);
                    continue;
                }
                this.add(board[i][j].getFiguras());
            }
        }
        Rompecabezas.Contenedor.validate();
    }

    public void Remover() {
        this.removeAll();
        Actualizar();
    }

}
```

he intentado de todo y nada ha funcionado tengo un JDK 12.02
tambien si es posible modificar para que solo cambie de imagen mas no que cree una nueva ventana
de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Agregar imagen de fondo a un JFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355961/agregar-imagen-de-fondo-a-un-jframe)

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que no tienes especificado un "Entry Point", revisa la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html). Realiza los siguientes pasos:

**Establecer el punto de entrada (Entry point) de una aplicación**.

a) Compilar el código Java, generando todos los archivos de clase del programa.

b) Crear un archivo de manifiesto `manifest.mf` que contenga la siguiente línea, definiendo la clase que contiene el `main()` , Main-Class: . :

```
Main-Class: rompecabezas.Rompecabezas
```

en algunos casos como en Netbeans este archivo se genera automaticamente, solo debes asegurar la configuración.

c) Luego creamos un archivo JAR llamado por ejemplo MyJar.jar definiendo el archivo manifesto y los archivos .class definiendo el paquete que en este caso es "rompecabezas", todo esto ingresando el siguiente comando:

```
jar cfm MyJar.jar Manifest.txt rompecabezas/*.class
```

Ahora puedes ejecutar el .jar de esta forma:

```
java -jar  MyJar.jar
```

Comment: Gracias amigo; esa fue una solución aunque el problema erradico mas en que las imagenes las tomaba como nulas tuve que colocar todo entre un try - catch y se soluciono el problema