# Uso de JRootPane

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de administración de locales y me vi con la necesidad de ponerle un fondo al `JFrame`. Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue hacer transparentes los paneles lo cual según estuve leyendo no era buena opción. Entonces encontré la existencia del `JRootPane`,el problema es que no encuentro ejemplos de su uso. Necesito ponerlo encima de algunos componentes y que contenga el fondo que necesito pero no se como hacerlo,me podrian guiar?Codigo de ejemplo:

```
private class Ventana extends JFrame{
    public void paintComponents(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    this.setRootPane(new Root());
    this.getRootPane().setVisible(true);
    
    }}

private class Root extends JRootPane{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/fondo.jpg")).getImage(),0,0,ventana.getWidth(),ventana.getHeight(),null);}}
```

Habia intentado algo como esto pero no funciono.

Comment: Pero si lo colocas al frente de todo, vas a tapar todo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Agregar imagen de fondo a un JFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355961/agregar-imagen-de-fondo-a-un-jframe)

Comment: "El panel de vidrio es útil cuando desea poder capturar eventos o pintar sobre un área que ya contiene uno o más componentes. Por ejemplo, puede desactivar los eventos del mouse para una región de varios componentes haciendo que el panel de vidrio intercepte los eventos. O puede mostrar una imagen sobre varios componentes utilizando el panel de vidrio.".Necesito ponerlo encima con un tamaño especifico para que cubra cierta zona

Comment: Necesitarías explicar cuál es "la necesidad" para que podamos decirte si manejar RootPane es la mejor alternativa. En muchos casos manejando visibilidad y eventos es suficiente. Sobrecargar `paintComponent` no debe ser la primera, sino la última opción.

Comment: Necesito que una parte del JFrame sea tapado por el rootpane y que este tenga una imagen.El punto es que no se como pintar el rootpane